# moving object between two preset location on scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to learn how to replicate this effect on the main screen of this website https://overv.io/

- The traget(booklets) starts off somewhere fixed and translate/rotates towards 0
- once it's reached it's original location, scrolling further down won't change any location
- scrolling back up with move the items back towards the location it stated.

Here's something which i think it should look like..

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    var speed = 1; //this should be adapted to the height of div
    var startdeg = 130; //
    var startx = 300;
    var starty =-300;
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); //using scrolling as variable
    var deg = (startdeg - scroll) / speed;
    var translatex = startx - scroll/ speed;
    var translatey = starty - scroll/ speed;
    //Here should be some conditioner or maybe a do-while loop to stop transforming once it reached it's original location?
    $(".logo").css({
        "transform": "translate("translatex+"px,"translatey+"px) rotate("+deg+"deg)",
    });   
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aavelyn/ktccxr6j/1/

PS: I'm fairly basic with javascript,jquery though i can fully understand the code presented. Thanks a lot!!

**(Thanks@Roy)Update:**

Here's on update on a working js, which targets a grid col div (tile3) from bootstrap and let's it return to it's original/target position after I scroll 200px.

Now i need help figuring out how to stop it, which means that once I scroll below 200px and the element is in it's position it stays there.
Also when I scroll above that "line" it should start move the elements back to it's starting position like overv.io

Thanks for you help!

```
window.onscroll = function() {

    var scrollHeight = 200;


    var speed = 1; //this should be adapted to the height of div
    var startdeg = 130; //
    var startx = 300;
    var starty =-300;


    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); //using scrolling as variable
    var deg = (startdeg - (startdeg/scrollHeight*scroll)) / speed;
    var translatex = (startx - (startx/scrollHeight*scroll))/ speed;
    var translatey = (starty - (starty/scrollHeight*scroll))/ speed;

    //Here should be some conditioner or maybe a do-while loop to stop transforming once it reached it's original location?
    $("#tile3").css({
        "transform": "translate(" +translatex+"px,"+translatey+"px) rotate("+deg+"deg)"
    });


};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your transform string is illformed. You forgot some `+` signs so that your string is effectively concatenated with your variables (i.e. before `translatex` and before `translatey`).

What you are looking for is:

```
$(".logo").css({
    "transform": "translate(" + translatex + "px," + translatey + "px) rotate(" + deg + "deg)"
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ktccxr6j/3/.

Also beware that safari still requires you to prefix `transform`with `-webkit-` so that it works properly (it is supposed to change soon though). `jQuery`handles it for you, but not your initial CSS.

**Edit:**
Following your comment I built this little helper (`scrollAnim`). I hope you will find it useful.

```js
function scrollAnim(target, scrollStart, scrollEnd, transforms){
    target = $(target);
    var scrollLength = scrollEnd - scrollStart;
    
    // Using jQuery's `on` method instead of `window.onscroll` allows to
    // add more than one handler (i.e. we can do this several times).
    $(window).on("scroll", function(){
     var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        // Get the progress of the animation in function of the scroll.
        var progress = (scroll - scrollStart) / scrollLength;
        // Restrict it to the [0,1] interval.
        progress = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, progress));
        
        // Build the transform css string using the properties of `transforms`.
        var cssTransform = "";
        for(var transformName in transforms){
            var transform = transforms[transformName];
            var transformUnit = transform.unit || "";
            // Calculate this property value in accordance with the current
            // scroll progress.
            var transformValue = (transform.end - transform.start) * progress + transform.start;
            // Append it to the transform string.
            cssTransform += transformName + "(" + transformValue + transformUnit + ") ";
        }
        target.css("transform", cssTransform);
    });
}

// The `transforms`'s property names must be proper css transform properties.
scrollAnim(".logo", 90, 490, {
    translateX: {
        start: 100,
        end: 300,
        unit: "px"
    },
    translateY: {
        start: 100,
        end: 490,
        unit: "px"
    },
    rotate: {
        start: 180,
        end: 0,
        unit: "deg"
    }
});
```

```css
.background{
    height:2000px;   
}
.logo{
    width:50px;
    height:70px;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    transform:translate(100px,100px) rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:translate(100px,100px) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="background">
    <div class="logo">
       <p>Logo</p>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Roy, Thanks a lot for your reply! 
Could you maybe help me with with the conditionals?
How do I let the transform stop when it's at its original place?
Thanks a lot

Comment: How do you define its "original place" ? You mean its target position ?

Comment: Yes, when the translate and transform reach 0. (so when the element is in its default position) 
I've worked out the math on how lot let the element reach it's target e.g. within 200px scolling. I've changed my post

Comment: Hi Roy, thanks a lot for the snippet, i'll breed over it :)

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider accepting my answer then :).